# TypeScript: define dynamic properties in proxy

Tags: javascript, typescript, proxy

I have the following call to a `watch`

```
const watch = hp.watch({
  running: false,
  time: 0,
  start: Date.now()
})
```

watch bassically just runs `new proxy()`, then sets some properties and returns the newly created `proxy` class nothing too fancy.

```
export function watch(item: { [key: string]: any }): proxy
export function watch(key: string, value: any): proxy
export function watch(...args: any[]): proxy {
  let prox = new proxy()
  if (args.length == 2) {
    prox[args[0]] = args[1]
  } else if (args.length == 1 && args[0] instanceof Object) {
    for (let itm in args[0]) {
      !(itm in prox) && (prox[itm] = args[0][itm])
    }
  }
  return prox
}
```

I then have an interface which looks like this:

```
export interface proxy {
  [key: string]: any
}
```

Here is the the `proxy` class which basically is just a wrapper.

```
namespace hp {
  export class proxy {
    public constructor() {
      return new Proxy(this, { /* Proxy stuff */})
    }
  }
}
```

In an editor that supports intellisense, it would be nice if I could have it suggest `running`, `time`, `start` after I type `watch.`.

I think I need to use a more advanced `interface` (or `type`) than the one I am using for that to happen. I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
export type watch<T> = {
  [A in keyof T]: T[A]
} 

export interface proxy {
  [key: string]: watch<any>
}
```

When doing `watch.time = 123` I get an error stating:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'watch'.

and when trying to get the value `let a = watch.time` I get this error:

> The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.

Comment: What's your type signature for `hp.watch()`?  Presumably you want it to look something like `watch<T>(obj: T): T & hp.proxy`, but without more info I'm not sure if that would solve it

Comment: @jcalz I have updated the question with how I am defining `watch`. Maybe I shouldn't be naming the function and the type the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the signature for `hp.watch()` to something like

```
export function watch<T>(item: T): proxy & T;
export function watch<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): proxy & Record<K, V>;
export function watch(...args: any[]): proxy {
  // impl
}
```

Then you have told TypeScript that the output of the function is both a `proxy` and has the same keys and value types as the thing you passed in.

Hope that helps; good luck!